# Share DB tables between two blogs on the same WP Multisite installation

Tags: multisite, database

Is it possible for two separate blogs running on the same multisite installation to share tables in the database?

By default, Wordpress adds the blog ID to the table prefix for all of the associated tables such that blog #1's posts are stored in the `wp_1_posts` table, blog #2's posts in the `wp_2_posts` table etc..

However, for my peculiar development workflow I would like to use blog #1 for public use and blog #2 for development while sharing database tables between them such that any changes made to either blog are reflected on both immediately (i.e. **both** blog #1 and blog #2's posts are stored in `wp_1_posts`, their users in `wp_1_users`, and so forth).

Any ideas?

Comment: But this way when you make changes to your development site you will also change the public site

Comment: I'm quite sure I've seen a plugin that cross-posts in MS environment, but can't find it right now... And I think it's **really** not advisable to go the "shared tables" way...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can switch back and forth between blogs on a multisite with `switch_to_blog` and `restore_current_blog`.

That should allow you to get anything you'd like and make queries as if you were actually on the other blog.

Check them out: 
http://codex.wordpress.org/WPMU_Functions/switch_to_blog
http://codex.wordpress.org/WPMU_Functions/restore_current_blog

We did a **lot** of this with [one of our recent sites](http://www.webdevelopmentgroup.com/work/shenandoah-university/).

Comment: ...sorry this took 2 years to answer.

Comment: I created my own solution at the time, but this one could be useful. Since no one else has answered, ill give the check to you.